# Why does Android Studio debugger complain about this code fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, kotlin

I want to inspect the values of several variables while the debugger is paused at a breakpoint. I swear I've done this before, but for some reason Android Studio has a problem with this Kotlin multiline code fragment:

```
println("Hello")
println("World")
```

It has no issue with the equivalent in Java:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("World");
```

Here's the screenshots:

[image: Kotlin multiline code fragment produces an error]
[image: Java multiline code fragment is fine]

Is this a bug in the IDE or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since the error highlight is on the second line, try putting a `;` at the end of the first line, and see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried semicolons at the end of both lines and there was no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with IDE it happens when you toggle language JAVA-Kotlin. For some reason i think it resets multiline code editor to single line editor. That's why if you can collapse it and expand again using arrows on top-right it gets fixed.